# Javascript: merge two arrays into single object without losing key order

Tags: javascript, arrays, mapreduce, reduce

I have some raw imdb data in two strings:

```
var headers = "ID   imdbID  Title   Year    Rating  Runtime Genre   Released    Director    Writer  Cast    Metacritic  imdbRating  imdbVotes   Poster  Plot    FullPlot    Language    Country Awards  lastUpdated";


const content = "1  tt0000001   Carmencita  1894    NOT RATED   1 min   Documentary, Short      William K.L. Dickson        Carmencita      5.8 1136    http://ia.media-imdb.com/images/M/MV5BMjAzNDEwMzk3OV5BMl5BanBnXkFtZTcwOTk4OTM5Ng@@._V1_SX300.jpg    Performing on what looks like a small wooden stage, wearing a dress with a hoop skirt and white high-heeled pumps, Carmencita does a dance with kicks and twirls, a smile always on her face.           USA     2016-05-04 00:03:31.600000000";
```

Of course I am cleaning out the tabs and spaces etc and creating two arrays like so:

```
const values = content.split(/(\t+)/).filter( (part) => !/\t/.test(part) );

let keys = headers.split(/(\s+)/).filter( (part) => !/\s+/.test(part) );
```

Now I want to map the keys in `keys` array to the values in the `values` array *accurately*. So I do a reduce like so:

```
var result = {};

values.reduce( (acc, val, index) => {
  return result[ keys[index] ] = val; 
}, result);
```

This gives me back a final `result` object that looks like this:

```
 {
  Cast: "1136",
  Director: "Carmencita",
  Genre: "Documentary, Short",
  ID: "1",
  imdbID: "tt0000001",
  imdbRating: "Performing on what looks like a small wooden stage, wearing a dress with a hoop skirt and white high-heeled pumps, Carmencita does a dance with kicks and twirls, a smile always on her face.",
  imdbVotes: "USA",
  Metacritic: "http://ia.media-imdb.com/images/M/MV5BMjAzNDEwMzk3OV5BMl5BanBnXkFtZTcwOTk4OTM5Ng@@._V1_SX300.jpg",
  Poster: "2016-05-04 00:03:31.600000000",
  Rating: "NOT RATED",
  Released: "William K.L. Dickson",
  Runtime: "1 min",
  Title: "Carmencita",
  Writer: "5.8",
  Year: "1894"
}
```

As you can see, the order is all mixed up! How do I get the right order in my data so I get `title` key mapped to the movie title value etc. ?

I am open to using a library like `lodash` to achieve this but can't tell what I should use? Here is a jsbin demo of the present state: https://jsbin.com/gekawi/edit?js,console

Comment: is the data separated by tab? if so, please include it into the question.

Comment: Yes - but the tabs are cleaned out

Comment: no, please supply the raw data.

Comment: raw data is in the first code snapshot and also in this jsbin: https://jsbin.com/gekawi/edit?js,console

Comment: I updated the question for accuracy @NinaScholz - had mistakenly stated arrays where I showed strings

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you take the raw data with the tabs inside, you could use them for splitting.

```js
var headers = "ID imdbID Title Year Rating Runtime Genre Released Director Writer Cast Metacritic imdbRating imdbVotes Poster Plot FullPlot Language Country Awards lastUpdated",
    content = "1 tt0000001 Carmencita 1894 NOT RATED 1 min Documentary, Short  William K.L. Dickson  Carmencita  5.8 1136 http://ia.media-imdb.com/images/M/MV5BMjAzNDEwMzk3OV5BMl5BanBnXkFtZTcwOTk4OTM5Ng@@._V1_SX300.jpg Performing on what looks like a small wooden stage, wearing a dress with a hoop skirt and white high-heeled pumps, Carmencita does a dance with kicks and twirls, a smile always on her face.   USA  2016-05-04 00:03:31.600000000",
    headerArray = headers.split(/\t/),
    contentArray = content.split(/\t/),
    object = {};

headerArray.forEach(function (k, i) {
    object[k] = contentArray[i];
});

console.log(object);
```

Comment: Awesome! Could you tell me why it didn't work when I split the data with spaces?

Comment: because you have some tabs together and you can not decide later which is what slot to assign.